# Difference between the words מיחייב and חייב

Tags: words, purim, talmud-bavli, intoxication, tractate-megillah

Rava in masheches megillah 7b famously said that one is obligated to drink until he cannot differentiate between Haman and Mordechai. My question is: Rava used the loshon of  מיחייב instead of חייב. Is this change teaching us something, or do they mean the same exact thing?

Comment: Why do you consider this as "instead" (why do you expect "חייב"?). The word "מיחייב" appears many times throughout the *talmud*, just like "חייב", and they both mean the same thing. One can say that "מיחייב" is the passive tense, like "מחויב אדם", but the two tenses are used interchangeably.

Comment: @Cauthon consider posting that as an answer.